# How to change the coordinates of a shape (i.e. oval) in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a program which when you press the S button it moves shape to the square below it on the grid. I have managed to get the shape to move the first time but after that it  just keeps getting bigger.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *  
root = Tk()
global y
y = 0
x = 0
def down(event):
    global y
    global x
    y = y+100
    x = x+ 100
    global pirate
    canvas.delete(pirate)
    pirate = canvas.create_oval((x,y), (100,100), fill = 'red')
    print(y)
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 1000)
canvas.pack()
for a in range (10):    
    i = a*100
    canvas.create_line((i,0), (i,1000))
for a in range (10):
    i = a*100
    canvas.create_line((0,i), (1000,i))

pirate = canvas.create_oval((x, y),(100, 100), fill = 'red')

root.bind('<Key - S>', down)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to delete and redraw the oval - you can just use `canvas.move(pirate, x, y)`. Not quite sure what the arguments x and y should be - never used the method myself. Just saw it in the docs.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Hey, if this looks like stealing, please add an answer. Since you said, you are not sure on how to do it, I thought I should add one. I'd happily delete mine upvote yours. :)

Comment: @Lafexlos - Nah, it's fine. Some of my top voted answers are me slightly expanding on things other people said in comments. You put more effort in than I did. I just glanced at the `Canvas` docs and saw a `move` method and figured I'd mention it.

Comment: x and y are deltas

Answer (score 4):

As ArtOfWarfare mentioned in comments, instead of creating new ovals everytime, create one and [move](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method) that thing around.

```
def down(event):
    canvas.move(pirate, 0, 100)
```

Above code is sufficient to move your oval one square down in your code.

Assuming you'll need to move oval other than just down, instead of binding only `S` to canvas, I think you should get all key events and do stuff depending on pressed char.

```
def keyPressed(event):
    if event.char.lower() == 's':  #move it down if it's S or s
        canvas.move(pirate, 0, 100)

root.bind('<Key>', keyPressed) #get all key pressed events
```

Comment: thanks so much this is really important i am getting paid £10 for doing the year gcse coursework. i am in year 9 and i love computer science if i do it within  a month i get £10 from my computer science teacher

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem that in python-tk the oval is NOT specified `create_oval(x,y,w,h)`, but `create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2)`. Hope that's helpful!